# How do I to debug a slow network? (ArchBang)

Tags: networking, dns, networkmanager, internet, systemd-networkd

**Situation:** MacBook Pro (late 2011/i3) with ArchBang has inconsistent network issues (very slow speed, pages fail to load, dns resolution failing).

**The workaround:** `systemctl restart NetworkManager.service` corrects the problem *but* it reoccurs every 10 - 20 minutes of continuous internet use

**Speedtest**

- MacBook: ArchBang, wireless, 8-10 Mbps
- MacOS: wireless, 85 Mbps
- iPhone: iOS, wireless, ~25Mbps
- iMac: ArchBang, wired, ~110Mbps

**MacBook ArchBang Setting**

- /etc/hostname: `macbang`
- /etc/hosts: normal/default

**Journalctl (`-f`)**

`dbus-daemon[490]: [system] Activation via systemd failed for unit 'dbus-org.freedesktop.resolve1.service': Unit dbus-org.freedesktop.resolve1.service not found.`

**Attempts at correcting the issue**

- Installed systemd-resolve and dnsmasq
- Installed dhcpcd and dhclient and ran them instead of NetworkManger's default.
- Changed IPV4 and IPV6 nameservers
- Reinstalled Arch
- Changing the wifi channel
- Router factory reset
- Installed broadcom-wl (with and without DKMS) b43
- Installed wicd and NetworkManger
- A number of combinations of the above.

All of these attempts (see the note below) have been successful for about three days, then the connection starts to become weak and unresponsive.

NOTE: Running `systemd-resolve` made the problem instantly worst, the computer stopped connecting altogether.

**How can I debug this issue ?**

Comment: Sounds a lot like DNS issue, try to set up your DNS in ArchBang to 1.1.1.1 and try again. are you using ethernet connection or wifi ?

Comment: @Kiwy by DNS you are talking about what's listed as the "nameserver" in the `/etc/resolv.conf` correct? And I am using wifi for the ArchBang. Should I change the ones for IPV6, too?

Comment: maybe your linux do not have proper driver for wifi 5Ghz. Though I have no clue how to check that.

Comment: @Kiwy My router is 2.4GHz, not 5GHz. And I tried changing the nameserver to `1.1.1.1` and that works just as good as what I was using.

Comment: are you talking in Mega bytes, or Mega Bits per second. Second [edit] your quesiton to make clear what test you run on wifi and what test you run on cable. 85Mb/s is possible over wifi but only with wifi n and wifi ac and above. Your macbook seems to connect with some old wifi b or g no more.

Comment: @Kiwy, I have updated the question. I don't understand "old wifi b or g no more." My software is up to date on both the Arch and the macOS.

Comment: compare the result of  `iw list` on both your wifi machine, I bet one is not able to run at the max wifi speed (probably because of some driver issue or something)

Comment: @kiwy I have added the results of `iwlist rate` to the question.

Comment: this require more debugging when the problem occur its too broad... ping router, ping dns ip, what's on iptables, what's on route, disk space etc etc.

Comment: It's too hard to help you. Try to do a wifi scan to identify if your wifi channel is not covered by too much other. Also your question starts to be very difficult to read, you should try to do short sentence, with list of tests and results.

Comment: however what is interessting is that your mac book wifi is probably not properly supported as you get more broadband from mac os than linux

Comment: @Kiwy I have tried to remove unnecessary information from the question. The   problem is that I don't know what information is needed. But thank you for    taking the time, it is appreciated.

Comment: @intika I have added the ping and disk space information to question. I do not know what iptables information would be helpful, nor do I understand what you mean when you say "on route."

Comment: @345422 thanks for updating that out, most of network problems like yours require an advanced expertise and debugging the problem while it occur, i guess the pings are not done when the system is failing... if you really want to solve that problem i would advice you to ask an other question asking how to debug when the problem occur with a very brief and short explanation of the problem. i don't think you will get any result by asking for a solution on a broad complex situation.

Comment: @intika I will do some more pings and add the results from when it fails. I will also start creating another question for debug help. Thanks.

Comment: it's not only about pings it's the whole thing you have to start over and do a full debug when it occur and even tho it could be difficult to identify the problem, pings alone wont do much

Comment: Nice [edit] your question is far more readable like that though still very hard to debug from outside your network. Hope you will get more help to identify the issue on your other question.

Comment: I suggested an edit that was accepted, the question is now answerable, and thus we could make a step to solve the problem :)

Comment: @345422 there we go, you have a full list on how to identify the problem and eventually help us to help you.

Comment: @Kiwy can you please double check my answer to see if i did not forget something ;) or post an other answer with further tests

Comment: @345422 you are welcome, just up-vote and accept the answer if it's helpful ;)

Answer (score 3):

First when the problem is not occurring, complex network issue like this one are very hard to debug , i advice you then to run the following tests when the problem is happening without trying to solve it to be able to identify the source of the issue.

- `ifconfig` (check the state of the network cards)
- ping to `127.0.0.1` (this check the internal communication)
- ping to `192.168.0.1` (ping to your gateway to check communication with the router)
- ping to `8.8.8.8` (to check the internet communication)
- ping to `www.google.com` (to check the dns resolution)
- dig to yahoo `dig www.yahoo.com` (to double check the dns resolution)
- `cat /etc/resolv.conf` (to find out what dns server is used and check if the dns config is fine)
- ping to the used DNS
- `journalctl -u NetworkManager.service` (check the network manager logs)
- `systemctl status NetworkManager.service` (check the network manager logs)
- `journalctl -x --no-pager` to check the overall logs, you can save the output to a file with (`journalctl -x --no-pager > journalfile`)
- `free` to check the state of the swap and ram.
- `traceroute www.google.com` to check what path is used for the internet
- `iptables -L` to check the rules under iptables
- check the routing table

  - `route -v -e -C`
  - `route -v -e`
  - `route -v -e -n`
- Also double check the other devices on wifi and ethernet, a speedtest on them will be enough if the problem is confirmed to be limited to the Archbang machine.

This should be enough to identify the source of the problem or at least point to the right direction where to make further tests.

You can edit your question to add the results of those commands if you did not figure out the issue while reading the results. Or post an other question with  the results details, those are valuable informations that will make the question on how to solve this issue answerable.